# Why I cant delete getters/setters defined in Object.defineProperties?

Tags: javascript

Somehow I can read the property of a getter, but I **can't delete** it.
(I **can** delete getters/setters defined w/o using Object.defineProperties)

```
var hello = {
    get num() {
        return 123;
    }
}
delete hello.num;
// returns true
```

However,

```
var hello = {};
Object.defineProperties(hello, {
    num: {
        get() {
            return 123;
        }
    }
}
delete hello.num;
// returns false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that using the .defineProperties their is a property called writable
By default, it is set to False set it to true there is also a property called configurable
set it to true as well You can see the following code example to achieve this

```
'use strict'
Object.defineProperty(window, 'hello',{ 
  get: ()=>"hello to you!",
  configurable: true //make this true


and for the writeable property you can set it like this:

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: True,
  writable: True,
  value: 'static'
});
```